# How to choose fitness function Heuristiclab for classification?

Tags: algorithm, genetic-programming

I have a classification problem. I want to use Heuristiclab to solve it.

When I tried to see fitness function parameter, there are only two textboxes for (start,end) I don't know what it means? And how can I choose the best fitness for my problem?

Here is the link:http://dev.heuristiclab.com/.

I use labeled dataset from UCI. The task is to use genetic optimization tool for predication.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain what "Heuristiclab" is. When I search for it online I only see this SO thread.

Comment: Also, further context and information about the problem you're attempting to solve would help. Having a "classification problem" can mean almost anything.

Comment: Here is the link:http://dev.heuristiclab.com/.... I use labeled dataset from UCI. The task is to use genetic optimization tool for predication.

Comment: Have a look at this [tutorial](http://dev.heuristiclab.com/trac.fcgi/wiki/Documentation/Howto/DefineCustomProblems) in particular the "Evaluation Function" section...